# releasing memory to os after using large number of unique_ptr - c++

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

Not able to figure out what is happening wrong.

Here is a simple code

```
size_t n_elem = 30000000; //careful! will allocate 1GB with unique_ptr
vector<unique_ptr<double> > tmp;
tmp.resize(n_elem);
for(size_t i=0; i<n_elem; i++){
   tmp[i] = unique_ptr<double>(new double((double)i));
}
tmp.clear();
//Some answers in Stack overflow seems to suggest this technique to force
//freeing, but does not seem to work.
vector<unique_ptr<double> > tmp1;
tmp.swap(tmp1);
```

When this finishes. The system monitor still shows 948 MB as allocated when it should show a spike in memory usage and then free everything right?. Even if the snippet is enclosed in braces {...} to ensure scope, I don't see any improvement. Once the memory is allocated, it does not seem to release until end of program.

Suspecting something with vector, I tried the below code, but with same behaviour.

```
{
    size_t n_elem = 30000000;
    unique_ptr<double>* tmp = new unique_ptr<double>[n_elem];
    for(size_t i=0; i<n_elem; i++)
        tmp[i] = unique_ptr<double>(new double((double)i));
    delete[] tmp;
}
```

However,

```
size_t n_elem = 30000000;
double *d_tmp;
d_tmp = new double[n_elem];
for(size_t i=0; i<n_elem; i++)
{
    d_tmp[i] = (double)i;
}
delete[] d_tmp;
```

This code shows the memory usage rising to about 260 MB and then being reduced as the array is deleted.

I tried using a class instead of a double and counting the number of times the destructor is  called with a static variable. In both cases, the destructor is called correct number of times.

I am not able to figure out what is wrong in the way I am using the unique_ptr and why it is not returning the memory allocated to the OS after destruction. The cpp reference seems to suggest this should happen automatically as the uniue_ptrs are getting destroyed. How do I make unique_ptr free the memory it has allocated and return it to the OS?

This happened on gcc 4.6 with ubuntu 12.04 and qtcreator qt project.

Comment: you are creating two array of unique_ptr and only delete one?

Comment: @yngum, No, the issue happens even in second code snippet. The snippets are run independently. The first snippet swaps an empty vector with the current vector.

Comment: second snippet also create two unique_ptr per each element

Comment: @yngum, Oh. How so? How do you suggest I change it? I just want to check for many unique_ptrs. The actual code will have a class containing two unique_ptrs but many instances of the class.

Comment: @sri - It's just *virtual* memory. The runtime might not care to give the address space back to the OS until the end of the program. The physical memory is still available to the OS (and other programs).

Comment: "*I am not able to figure out what is wrong ... and why it is not returning the memory allocated to the OS after destruction.*" That's because nothing is wrong. There are two types of memory, physical memory (RAM) and virtual memory (address space). It is not returning RAM because there is no need. Unless you lock something in physical memory (which doesn't happen here) the RAM belongs to the OS anyway. It is not returning virtual memory because there is no need either. Virtual memory is not a scarce resource. It's working set that's scarce, and that *is* returned.

Answer (score 0):

slightly change your code

```
tmp.clear(); // it is not needed
{
  //Some answers in Stack overflow seems to suggest this technique to force
  //freeing, but does not seem to work.
  vector<unique_ptr<double> > tmp1;
  tmp.swap(tmp1);
}
// measure memory here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

```
tmp[i] = unique_ptr<double>(new double((double)i));
```

To:

```
tmp[i].reset(new double((double)i));
```

Also, I won't presume to know what you're intending to do (or to know better), but if what you're trying to replicate is a dynamically allocated double array, you don't need to make it hold `unique_ptr`'s. Just use a straight up `vector<double>`. Otherwise, you're creating a `unique_ptr` for every single `double` you want to store. This is *not* the same as an array which is continuously allocated (thus exploiting locality/caching). This seems to incur unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Thanks. But that doesn't seem to resolve the issue either. This is just an isolated case. The unique pointer is actually used inside a class for a tree based representation which may have some unknown number of children. I used unique_ptr to not worry about clean up when objects are destroyed, but I noticed that the memory never seems to go down. I suspected the code in the class, but it turns out I was able to replicate the same behavior in these code snippets.

Comment: @sri Are you actually checking with the sample code you gave? Or are you using `unique_ptr<SomeClass>` in your tests instead? I just ran it through valgrind and it says there are no memory leaks. As a side note, in response to your comment, I don't mean to badger about this but it seems like you should be able to use `vector<NodeClass> children;` in your class. I don't think there's a need to have `unique_ptrs` in there.

Comment: I am checking with the sample code in the question. I too checked that there were no memory leaks, however, it does not seem to release memory to os until after program exit which can be bothersome. I'll try the vector idea and see how it goes.

Comment: @sri Indeed I get what you mean, however, valgrind supposedly checks for memory leaks throughout the program. For example if I change the code to declare an array (`new double[]`) and don't `delete` it, it'll tell me, even though by the end of the program the OS reclaims the memory as you say.

Comment: @sri Yeah that's weird. Just stepped through it in gdb and didn't notice any leaks. The memory gets reclaimed right after `clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, memory managers ask the OS for more memory when they need it, but don't try to give it back to the OS when they're done. The latter is hard to do in general, because heap usage tends to splatter, and there is too much bookkeeping involved in knowing when OS-sized memory blocks are no longer needed. Further, even if the memory manager does that, the OS might leave that memory allocated to your program until it's needed elsewhere, so OS tools that report memory usage don't reflect what's actually used by your application.

The real question here is whether this excess memory creates a problem; typically the OS manages large working sets by swapping to disk; unused memory blocks clutter the backing store, but don't tie up RAM.